# How to get stock rating on Robin_Stocks robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings function

Tags: python

Peeps, 
I am using robin_stocks to get stock quotes Robinhood and interested in getting rating of stock using this function: robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings as follow:

```
quotes = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings('AAPL', )
print(quotes)
```

I get a very long string as follow (cut it short to save space here) :

```
{'summary': {'num_buy_ratings': 26, 'num_hold_ratings': 13, 'num_sell_ratings': 3 ....
```

How can I modify my code to get just the numbers i.e. 26, 13, and 3 so that I can run my calculations.

if I use:

```
quotes = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings('AAPL', 'num_buy_ratings')
```

I get error as follow:

```
Error: The keyword "num_buy_ratings" is not a key in the dictionary.
```

I am not advance in python, if you can help, I very much appreciate it.
Thanks,

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want the list of those numbers?

Comment: So I found out if I do as follow: quotes = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings ('AAPL', 'summary') it will print shorter output, as this: {'num_buy_ratings': 26, 'num_hold_ratings': 13, 'num_sell_ratings': 3} but I am only interested in the numbers if I can extract them or change the code.  thnx

Comment: Also iI am thinking if there is not an easy solution to what I am asking, then perhaps I can write the output to csv, then read content of csv as variables to do my calculations.  However I hope there is a simple way to just output the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned on the comment that from:

```
quotes = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings ('AAPL', 'summary')
```

you get

```
{'num_buy_ratings': 26, 'num_hold_ratings': 13, 'num_sell_ratings': 3}
```

Which means that it is a `dict`
So if you just want the numbers than you can do:

```
quotes = robin_stocks.stocks.get_ratings ('AAPL', 'summary').values()
```